# How to change border color of a button?

Tags: javascript, button, next.js, colors, border

I have been trying to change the border color of a button

I tried doing borderColor but it was pointless:

```
borderColor: '#FFFFFF'
```

Expected [outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbag8.png)

Code:

```
headerBtn: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    fontSize: '16px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    letterSpacing: '-0.16px',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    color: '#ffffff',
    padding: '6.5px 24px',
    display: ['none', null, null, null, 'inline-block'],
    ml: ['0', null, null, 'auto', '0'],
    mr: ['0', null, null, '20px', '0'],
    '&:hover': {
      color: '#000000',
    },
  }
```

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TITEd.png) from the code above

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLsW3.png) while hover

Comment: read [ask] and provide a [mre]. how is the background white when you're hovering when there is no such rule.

Comment: this is extremely basic, I suggest you try doing some search on your own before attempting questions of this level. As for how to change css of elements: $("#element").css("border-color", "#d2d6de");
You said you wanted to "change" the colour. Change how? With a button? on document load? when do you want to run the function that will change it?

Comment: I just want to have a fixed border color which would be black. I tried searching but couldn't find anything related to it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use

border-color: #ffffff;

Try the below code.

```
.headerBtn {
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -0.16px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 6.5px 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.headerBtn:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```